# Submit an App by Url to Firefox Marketplace

Tags: marketplace, firefox-os

I can install it with URL, but i can't upload to firefox marketplace.

but i have 2 errors:

```
JSON Parse Error

Error: The webapp extension could not be parsed due to a syntax error in the JSON.
No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

well the json is this:

```
{
  "name": "Snake",
  "description": "Snake in html and js",
  "launch_path": "/index.html",
  "developer": {
    "name": "ZiTAL",
    "url": "https://github.com/ZiTAL/snakejs"
  },
 "icons": {
    "128": "/img/snake-128.png"
  },  
"installs_allowed_from": ["*"]
}
```

Second error:

```
Manifests must be served with the HTTP header "Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json". See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Apps/Manifest#Serving_manifests for more information.
```

well if i downloaded with wget:

```
wget http://myurl/manifest.webapp
```

the header is OK

```
HTTP eskaera bidalia, erantzunaren zain... 200 OK
Luzera: 267 [application/x-web-app-manifest+json]
Saving to: ‘manifest.webapp’
```

Comment: That is interesting. Usually this error happens when the manifest file is not served correctly but it looks like you have proper `.htaccess` in place. Use the validator to see if it gives any more information about the problem: https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/validator

Comment: aaah!!! i need to put the webapp URL to validate the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate the app, you need to put the **manifest.webapp** url, not the app url:

```
http://myurl/manifest.webapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Second error:

You could try `wget --save-headers` and look in the output file, if the Content-Type header is really correct...

Comment: i answered my question, thank you for your attention.